# Error when creating R library on vertica : "basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid"

Tags: c++, r, vertica

I'm trying to create a R language library in HP Vertica.
I've been able to do it on a different machine, but now when I try to do it on a different machine I get this error messsage :

```
create library rhlib as 'foo.r' language 'R';
ROLLBACK 3399:  Failure in UDx RPC call InvokeSetExecContext(): Error calling setupContext() in User Defined Object [] at [/scratch_a/release/vbuild/vertica/UDxFence/vertica-udx-R.cpp:112], error code: 0, message: Exception in Validate Library:basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid
```

What can be the issue? Is my R language pack not installed correctly?

Comment: Somewhere in your code you're trying to construct an `std::basic_string` (`std::string` or `std::wstring`) with `nullptr` instead of a pointer to an array of characters.

Comment: I guess that's something to do with the C++ which I know nothing about. Can you think of a reason it would come from the R code? it is basically a text file...

Comment: Did you use Vertica's rpm to install R?

Comment: @ChristopherLouden, yes I have.

Comment: I found the solution is within the R code. Apparently one of the R libraries fails to load. I added a separate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058225/rcpp-package-and-forecast-package-issues).

Comment: Apparently this has to do with cose errors. Since there is a different config for each node I had to add in an automatic conf which solved it.