# Rcpp package and Forecast package issues (old versions)

Tags: r, rcpp, vertica

I have two linux machines with R version 3.0.0

I've installed the forecast package version 4.8 on both machines.

Both machines have the same version of dependencies :

```
>ip <- installed.packages()
>ip[c("forecast","Rcpp","RcppArmadillo"),c("Package","Version")]
              Package         Version
forecast      "forecast"      "4.8"
Rcpp          "Rcpp"          "0.10.2"
RcppArmadillo "RcppArmadillo" "0.4.000.4"
```

But when I run it on the other node I get the following error :

```
>library(forecast)
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  namespace ‘Rcpp’ 0.10.2 is already loaded, but >= 0.11.0 is required
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘forecast’
```

These R versions are a little old because they are used in Vertica's 'R language pack' in which I can't upgrade the version and the Rcpp package.

How can I solve this or research the problem further?

Comment: I'm not understanding what this has to do with Vertica.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to talk to Vertica?

In short, do one of these things:

- go with your vendor, and stick to old versions (which is bad: R 3.0.0 has been superseded by 3.0.1 and 3.0.2 with 3.0.3 coming out next week; Rcpp 0.10.2 is *ancient*, we are at 0.11.0 now);
- update your packages, but make sure yo do it in lockstep (ie use the Rcpp version that was current when your version of forecast was built -- which you currently violate using a version that need Rcpp 0.11.0 when you only have Rcpp 0.10.2 [ very old !! ];
- ignore your vendor and update in a local library, pre-pend the `.libPaths()` (see `help(Startup)` for details)

Lastly, if I may, I find the title of your question misleading. I'd say the error is due to your installation of non-matching version onto your base R (from Vertica). The packages Rcpp, RcppArmadillo and forecast all work just fine in a normal environment.

Comment: I'm contacting them in parallel, don't think they can say much. I'll give your suggestions a shot.

Comment: So unbreak your system by removing the versions that broke things, presumably a too-recent-for-Vertica version of forecast.

Comment: Unless you have paid support through Vertica it's unlikely you'll get much help.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, I have paid support. But that doesn't mean I necessary get much help :)

Comment: Sounds like we're in the same boat